EXC_BAD_ACCESS while reading file on iOS 16
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::string myText;
    std::ifstream MyReadFile("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist");
    while (std::getline(MyReadFile, myText)) {
        std::cout << myText;
    }
    MyReadFile.close();
}


This code is compiled with XCode12/13/14 (arch: arm64e) and tested with iPhone11+iOS14.8/iPhone11+iOS16.5.
It run properly on iOS14.8 but crash on iOS16.5. The exception call stack shows an error with virual function
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200001ecb75f50)
Note: Possible pointer authentication failure detected.
Found authenticated load instruction at address=0x1004a5224  (__locale:1002:16).

  * frame #0: 0x00000001004a5224 testapp`std::__1::codecvt<char, char, __mbstate_t>::always_noconv[abi:v15006](this=0x00000001e9a4a2c0) const at __locale:1002:16
    frame #1: 0x00000001004a6a60 testapp`std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(this=0x000000016f963358) at fstream:316:35
    frame #2: 0x00000001004a6880 testapp`std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(this=0x000000016f963358) at fstream:312:1
    frame #3: 0x00000001004a220c testapp`std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(this=0x000000016f963348, __s="/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist", __mode=8) at fstream:1160:14
    frame #4: 0x00000001004a202c testapp`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016f963840) at main.mm:98:19
    frame #5: 0x00000001009d5dec dyld`start + 2220

code in __locale:
template <>
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>
    : public locale::facet,
      public codecvt_base
{
public:
    typedef char      intern_type;
    typedef char      extern_type;
    typedef mbstate_t state_type;

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    explicit codecvt(size_t __refs = 0)
        : locale::facet(__refs) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    result out(state_type& __st,
               const intern_type* __frm, const intern_type* __frm_end, const intern_type*& __frm_nxt,
               extern_type* __to, extern_type* __to_end, extern_type*& __to_nxt) const
    {
        return do_out(__st, __frm, __frm_end, __frm_nxt, __to, __to_end, __to_nxt);
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    result unshift(state_type& __st,
                   extern_type* __to, extern_type* __to_end, extern_type*& __to_nxt) const
    {
        return do_unshift(__st, __to, __to_end, __to_nxt);
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    result in(state_type& __st,
              const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __frm_end, const extern_type*& __frm_nxt,
              intern_type* __to, intern_type* __to_end, intern_type*& __to_nxt) const
    {
        return do_in(__st, __frm, __frm_end, __frm_nxt, __to, __to_end, __to_nxt);
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    int encoding() const  _NOEXCEPT
    {
        return do_encoding();
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    bool always_noconv() const  _NOEXCEPT
    {
        return do_always_noconv();
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    int length(state_type& __st, const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __end, size_t __mx) const
    {
        return do_length(__st, __frm, __end, __mx);
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    int max_length() const  _NOEXCEPT
    {
        return do_max_length();
    }

    static locale::id id;

protected:
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    explicit codecvt(const char*, size_t __refs = 0)
        : locale::facet(__refs) {}

    ~codecvt();

    virtual result do_out(state_type& __st,
                          const intern_type* __frm, const intern_type* __frm_end, const intern_type*& __frm_nxt,
                          extern_type* __to, extern_type* __to_end, extern_type*& __to_nxt) const;
    virtual result do_in(state_type& __st,
                         const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __frm_end, const extern_type*& __frm_nxt,
                         intern_type* __to, intern_type* __to_end, intern_type*& __to_nxt) const;
    virtual result do_unshift(state_type& __st,
                              extern_type* __to, extern_type* __to_end, extern_type*& __to_nxt) const;
    virtual int do_encoding() const  _NOEXCEPT;
    virtual bool do_always_noconv() const  _NOEXCEPT;
    virtual int do_length(state_type& __st, const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __end, size_t __mx) const;
    virtual int do_max_length() const  _NOEXCEPT;
};

...

bool always_noconv() const  _NOEXCEPT
    {
        return do_always_noconv();
    }

Very weird!
There is another one of standard I/O functions crash(caused by virtual functions too!):
There will be no crash if "std::hex" removed.
std::string uint32_to_hex1(uint32_t i, bool fill0) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    if (fill0) {
        stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << i;
    } else {
        stream << std::hex << i;
    }
    return stream.str();
}

Does arm64e has poor support of c++, even standard library will crash!
How to fix the error on iOS16?

The failing address and the address of your string are suspiciously similar, except off by one bit. Is this reproducible? Are you sure you're not linking a debug build with release libraries or somesuch?

It's normal, the header part of the c++ will be compile together(class definition and template), so they are in one module adress 'testapp'. .It is all fine if I compile it to arm64 arch. but for arm64e, it will crash
